# Access list as a hash

Tags: perl, list, hash, syntax

I can directly access an element within a list:

```
$foo = (qw(a b c))[2]; # $foo = "c"
```

And I can assign a list to a hash:

```
%h = (a=>0, b=>1, c=>2);
$foo = $h{c}; # $foo = 2
```

So, why can't I directly treat a list as a hash?

```
$foo = (a=>0, b=>1, c=>2){c}; # Syntax error
```

The closest I could find is to create a hashref:

```
$foo = {a=>0, b=>1, c=>2}->{c};
```

Is there a correct syntax to access a list as a hash or why not?

Comment: Short answer: creating a hash is a fairly expensive operation, whereas the representation of a list and an array are quite similar. The conceptual differences between a hash and a list are also quite large.

Comment: The conversion only occurs when assigning a list to a hash variable, because that's a common need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a list as a hash because lists aren't hashes. :)

The `=>` ("fat comma") operator is the same as `,`, with the additional feature that it quotes barewords on the left-hand-side. So when you write this:

```
( a=>0, b=>1, c=>2 )
```

It's exactly the same as this:

```
( 'a', 0, 'b', 1, 'c', 2 )
```

And that's not a hash, it's just a list.

Lists are ephemeral things that live on the stack; as you correctly point out they can be assigned to both arrays and hashes, but they are not the same as arrays and hashes.

A hash needs to be constructed before it can be used. Any key/value list assigned to it needs to have the keys hashed and the buckets allocated and the values placed in the buckets. So when you write:

```
$foo = {a=>0, b=>1, c=>2}->{c};
```

What's happening is:

1. The elements in the list ( 'a', 0, 'b', 1, 'c', 2 ) are put onto the stack
2. An anonymous hash is constructed by the `{ LIST }` operator
3. The list elements are popped off the stack and assigned to the hash, turning them into keys and values
4. A reference to that hash is returned.
5. The reference is dereferenced by the `->` operator
6. The key `c` is looked up, and
7. Its value returned, reducing the expression to `$foo = 2`

So why can you write `(qw(a b c))[2]` if a list is not an array? Well, internally the stack is just an array of `SV *`'s so I imagine that putting the ability to subscript it was simple and seemed like a good idea.

Here's an article by a really cool guy which you may also find enlightening: [Arrays vs. Lists in Perl: What's the Difference?](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl)

Answer (score 0):

No. Because lists are not hashes.
The closest that you could do is

```
my $foo = (a=>0,b=>1,c=>2)[5]; 
printf("$foo\n");
```

which will print

```
2
```

as the above code is identical as

```
my $foo = ('a',0,'b',1,'c',2)[5]; 
printf("$foo\n");
```